# What is the better way of making an SQL statement in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I was looking up how to insert into my database via sql and I noticed the way I had seen a person do an sql statement was different from the way I had done it and and now I'm wondering which way is better.

An example of what I had done in a previous (select) statement.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Variables.Default.sqlConString);
conn.Open();
string builtCmd = Variables.Default.returnUserNameSql1 + usersInput + Variables.Default.returnUsernameSql2;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(builtCmd, conn);

usersInput is a string.
Variables.Default.returnUserNameSql1 = SELECT [Username] from [dbo].[LoginDetails] WHERE [Username] = '
returnUsernameSql2 = '
```

What I have seen online (not my query):

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO klant(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@param1,@param2,@param3)";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", klantId));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param2", klantNaam));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param3", klantVoornaam));
```

Is the use of the Parameters function (?) better? If so in what way?

Thanks for your time.

I modified my original query thanks to the help of some of the comments here. I'll post it if anyone's interested:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Variables.Default.sqlConString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Variables.Default.returnUserNameSql, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(Variables.Default.param1, usersInput));
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        usernameTaken = reader.Read();
                        cmd.Dispose();
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
```

Comment: It's better to use parameters, see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: it's better to use parameters and stored procs* Get rid of the inline SQL- They have that online like that so you can read it :P. You can also specify the SqlParameter objects type, direction, value, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up "SQL Injection attack" on google. [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) says hello. And then realize that your way is not bad, it is a security nightmare because everyone with access to your program can execute whatever SQL he wants.

Comment: "Bobby Tables says hello"?

Comment: Added the link. It is a comi strip about a child named "Bobby; -- Drop Table Students" ;)

Comment: I see! Thank you very much, this never crossed my mind!

Comment: might want to change 'not bad' to 'not _only_ bad'

Comment: @tomtom I don't suppose you could give me an example of how to do the first select query? I'm having troubles making it :/.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Injection is certainly an *important* reason not to use string concatenation, but there are a few others:

- **string delimiters** - you'd need to include string delimiters in your SQL statement, and if the values you concatenate include them as well, you'll likely get syntax errors.  With parameters you don't need string delimiters, and values with apostro[phes or quotes don't affect the SQL syntax.
- **string conversion of values** - you'd need to convert all non-string values (numbers, dates, etc.) to strings, and ensure that their string represenatations are *exactly* reversible by the server.  This is especially problematic for dates since the same string can represent two different dates depending on the culture of the server.  With parameters, the values are passed without translation, so there's no risk that the server misinterprets values.
- **pre-compilation** - with concatenation, the server must reanalyze each query to determine the "best" plan.  With parameters, the server can re-use a cached plan since the actual *query* has been issued before, just with different *parameters*.  This doesn't mean that queries will *always* perform faster, and in some cases can actually cause *bad* plans to be used, but it is a consideration if you issue millions of queries that only differ in parameter values.